# How can I dynamically change the menu links in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, menubar

In one of my projects, I have to change the `menu links` according to my `content page`. Its like, if my "content page" is `page 1`, then my menu links will be `Menu 1, Menu 2, Menu 3,...`, if my content page is `page 2`, my menu links will be `Menu A, Menu B, Menu C,...`.

Example:
in my header, `menu bar` is :

```
<ul>
   <li><?php echo $this->Html->link("Menu 1",array('controller'=>'controllers','action'=>'menu1','full_base'=>true));?></li>
   <li><?php echo $this->Html->link("Menu 2",array('controller'=>'controllers','action'=>'menu2','full_base'=>true));?></li>
</ul>
```

What I want is, when I am in page "any_page.ctp"(means, when I am in a function "anyPage"), the menu bar will be automatically changed to this :

```
<ul>
   <li><?php echo $this->Html->link("Menu A",array('controller'=>'controllers','action'=>'menuA','full_base'=>true));?></li>
   <li><?php echo $this->Html->link("Menu B",array('controller'=>'controllers','action'=>'menuB','full_base'=>true));?></li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the `Menu(s)` according to my pages. Is there any way to do this, in `CakePHP` ?

Please let me know if any more explanation is needed.

Comment: Controller is the wrong place to do it, respect the MVC pattern and do it in a view.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it in the "View" part (either in a "view" file, or in the "header" file). But, can you please tell me how to do it ?@burzum

Comment: its all about if else. If you wants to get an idea then update your question with specific and clear example.

Comment: I changed the problem description with an example. Can you try to solve my problem now ? @FazalRasel

Comment: what you are trying, i think, its not a good idea... You are changing action on url means you have to create several actions like menu1, menu2, menuA, menuB along with their view.... It would be good to use query string or pass parameter to just to one action....Well, Still its not clear your purpose, but you can try what @schnauss suggested...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving out all the `<li>`'s and CSS styling you might want to use, you could try something like this in your navbar.

```
if ($this->params['action'] == 'page1') {
    echo "menu item 1";
    echo "menu item 1";
    echo "menu item 1";
} elseif ($this->params['action'] == 'page2') {
    echo "menu item A";
    echo "menu item B";
    echo "menu item C";
} else {
    echo "something else A";
    echo "something else B";
    echo "something else C";
}
```

Basically, if you want to access your current action in a view, you can get it via `$this->params['action']`. To see other variables that are available, try using `debug($this->params)`.

Comment: Its a new thing for me, I didn't know that "params" array is there for me. Thanks a lot. @schnauss

Answer (score 0):

you can create elements for menu.
for example you want to create the menu for page 1.

```
<ul>
      <li><?php echo $this->Html->link("Menu",array('controller'=>'controllers','action'=>'menu1','full_base'=>true));?></li>
      <li><?php echo $this->Html->link("Menu 2",array('controller'=>'controllers','action'=>'menu2','full_base'=>true));?></li>   
</ul>
```

Save this into a file in the path -> app/View/Elements/page1_menu.ctp (filename is just an example)

Then later in view where you display your menu. (For example your url is /users/page1)

```
if($this->params["controller"]=="users" && $this->params["action"]=="page1" ){
  echo $this->element('page1_menu');
}
```

Comment: i suggest using elements if you are using the same menu more than once so you can just reuse the element.

Comment: using elements is good if you are using the same snippet of code more than once. but if you will just use it once @schnauss' answer will be a good option :)